# Why does HTML form action call for a URL not produce the same result as pasting URL into Browser?

Tags: html, forms, cs50

I am in CS50 Web Programming class and I am trying to build my own front end for a google image search. I have stripped down my code to a very basic form and I am still unable to get the expected response. If I paste "https://www.google.ca/search?q=cat" into the URL in chrome, I receive the normal google response of a list of websites related to cats. However when I run my code and click on the submit button, I am redirected to "https://www.google.ca/webhp"
My code is:
`<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <form id="image_form" action="https://www.google.ca/search?q=cat" method="get"> <input type="submit" value="Google Search"> </form> </html>`

Comment: You don't have a field that contains your query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing you are doing and found that when we use get method in form for redirecting its removing everything after '?' due to some html rules.

So I fixed this by doing these changes:

```
    <form action="https://www.google.ca/search" method="get">
      <input type="hidden" name="q" value="cat"/> 
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Ayan, Thank you, That totally has helped me move forward. I have now moved to using Javascript to call the URL instead of HTML.

Comment: yes using Javascript is better. keep learning good luck :)